# Send app to background and show the app(s) in the below window

Tags: iphone, button, background, home-button

I dont want my app to run in background, I only want to give the user the option to close his/her other app(s) when my app gets a memory warning. That is, my app shows an alert view with Cancel and OK buttons. If s/he touches OK, then the twice push on the home button is simulated. Is it possible?

I have this as an option in their settings, i.e. if they want to see the memory warning or not. I mentioned that I don't want my app running in background, because I see many questions asked here about running their own app in background. It is not relevant to my question, I just wanted to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

When your app receives a memory warning it should act responsibly and free memory where it can. From the [Apple docs](http://www.apple.com.cn/developer/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf)

> When a view controller receives a memory warning
>   (didReceiveMemoryWarning), it should relinquish ownership of resources
>   that are currently not needed and that can be recreated later if
>   required.

I'm not quite sure what this has to do with not running your app in the background.

Answer (score 3):

Not with public APIs.
Beside that, when you receive a memory warning you should only take care of the resources you allocate and use, and not ask someone else to free memory instead of you.

Comment: Actually, when a new app is opened that requires more memory than is currently available, iOS automatically closes suspended apps in least recently used order.